# my sql queries 2 tables into 1 tables different case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two queries

```
SELECT
IF(t_booking_details.status = 1, t_room.code, (IF (t_stay_info.room IS null , t_room.code,null))) as room
FROM t_stay_info
INNER JOIN t_booking_details
ON t_stay_info.code = t_booking_details.stayInfo
RIGHT JOIN t_room
ON t_room.code = t_stay_info.room
INNER JOIN t_room_type
ON t_room_type.code = t_room.roomType
WHERE t_room_type.name = "Deluxe Double"
```

result :

```
+-------+
| room  |
+-------+
| NULL  |
| code2 |
| code3 |
| code4 |
+-------+
```

```
SELECT 
IF(t_reservation.`status` = 1, t_room.code, (IF (t_stay_info.room IS null , t_room.code,null))) as room
FROM t_stay_info
INNER JOIN t_reservation
ON t_stay_info.code = t_reservation.stayInfo 
RIGHT JOIN t_room
ON t_room.code = t_stay_info.room 
INNER JOIN t_room_type  
ON t_room_type.code = t_room.roomType
WHERE t_room_type.name = "Deluxe Double"
```

result

```
+-------+
| room  |
+-------+
| code1 |
| code2 |
| code3 |
| NULL  |
+-------+
```

How can the results be combined so that one obtains:

```
+-------+
| room  |
+-------+
| NULL  |
| code2 |
| code3 |
| NULL  |
+-------+
```

Comment: pardon me i've got wrong copy paste :)

the first query should be like this

SELECT 
IF(t_booking_details.`status` = 1, t_room.code, (IF (t_stay_info.room IS null , t_room.code,null))) as room
FROM t_stay_info
INNER JOIN t_booking_details
ON t_stay_info.code = t_booking_details.stayInfo 
RIGHT JOIN t_room
ON t_room.code = t_stay_info.room 
INNER JOIN t_room_type  
ON t_room_type.code = t_room.roomType
WHERE t_room_type.name = "Deluxe Double"

Comment: Could we get sample starting data, please?  The `RIGHT JOIN` is giving me headaches - most of the time I start from the "guaranteed" entity (`t_room`/`t_room_type` in this case), then _left_ join; I feel it makes reasoning about things much easier.  If the `t_`s are short for "table", you've essentially got the bad form of Hungarian notation: they become meaningless noise with any good db viewer

Comment: yap i think so t_s is not good form but my company have company rules, well so i just followed that

okay, explanation from first query is 
when someone book a room so the data will save in t_booking , t_booking_details and t_stay_info.

because t_booking_details could store more than 1 roomType, and T_stay_info is for store room and guest information with some bill etc.

t_booking_details have status too.

Comment: the relationship between t_stay_info and t_booking details are INNER JOIN.t_booking_details have status too. 1 SIGN for voided and 0 sign for active, so when
IF(t_booking_details.status = 1, t_room.code, (IF (t_stay_info.room IS null , t_room.code,null))) as room FROM t_stay_info so it means available rooms. when some rooms have been booked there is NULL value appear because the status is 0. -->

Comment: the same as t_reservation that have relationship with t_stay_info. when someone have reserved 1 room the status will change to 0 , the available rooms will have NULL values for that .Now i want to combine that into 1 tables , available rooms could detect booking and reservation. so the result will be like above. sory for my bad english

Comment: I asked for sample starting data, not this explanation (which is a bit opaque, and would have been better edited into the question, anyways.  Post the data that gives you the current/desired results you already listed (ie, let us verify your current work).  As a side note, only reporting one non-key column is pointless - how are you supposed to be able to tell the difference between the first `null` and the `second`?  And it seems like you should be getting more rows, too (ie, there's probably more than one room of type `"Double Deluxe"`, and probably reserved more than once too).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749857/mysql-case-room-availability?noredirect=1#comment38398806_24749857