# MySQL Case Room Availability

Tags: mysql, sql

i have tables : booking, reservation, room , stayed_information

sample data : 
Okay first sorry for inconvenience from the encryption sample data

this is the table that relational with room_type

```
   mysql> SELECT
        -> stay_info.room, room.code
        -> FROM stay_info
        -> RIGHT JOIN t_room
        -> ON stay_info.room = room.code
        -> INNER JOIN room_type
        -> ON room_type.code = room.roomType
        -> WHERE room_type.name = "Deluxe Double";




+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| room                                 | code                                 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| NULL                                 | 26a73433-d0cc-4e93-95d9-453d362e85a7 |
| NULL                                 | 2b166d4f-2fe4-404c-beff-482c7d81c103 |
| NULL                                 | 3efc3bff-9c02-43ef-a494-e887a342c1f5 |
| NULL                                 | 7e0ebe37-a23a-46b6-9351-ba0c952ed33e |
| NULL                                 | 9574eb5f-58de-427f-859e-d8b61e289836 |
| NULL                                 | 9ee50e45-f92b-46bd-bf3e-fc818a96a81f |
| NULL                                 | d72f3f7e-c9d2-44d8-8767-66d2a1477a1b |
| NULL                                 | e25587a3-3dc1-4c0f-b4c2-68a1da538bd7 |
| NULL                                 | e2d7fe3a-06e2-48df-a083-6c8eaeeefc22 |
| NULL                                 | fadc4d40-33b2-4545-98fe-e52d351c50f9 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

and if i have reservation process

```
mysql> SELECT
    -> stay_info.room, IF(reservation.`status` = 1, room.code, (IF (stay
_info.room IS null , room.code,null))) as code
    -> FROM stay_info
    -> INNER JOIN reservation
    -> ON reservation.stayInfo = stay_info.code
    -> RIGHT JOIN room
    -> ON stay_info.room = room.code
    -> INNER JOIN room_type
    -> ON room_type.code = room.roomType
    -> WHERE room_type.name = "Deluxe Double" ;





+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| room                                 | code                                 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| NULL                                 | 26a73433-d0cc-4e93-95d9-453d362e85a7 |
| NULL                                 | 2b166d4f-2fe4-404c-beff-482c7d81c103 |
| NULL                                 | 3efc3bff-9c02-43ef-a494-e887a342c1f5 |
| NULL                                 | 7e0ebe37-a23a-46b6-9351-ba0c952ed33e |
| NULL                                 | 9574eb5f-58de-427f-859e-d8b61e289836 |
| NULL                                 | 9ee50e45-f92b-46bd-bf3e-fc818a96a81f |
| NULL                                 | d72f3f7e-c9d2-44d8-8767-66d2a1477a1b |
| e25587a3-3dc1-4c0f-b4c2-68a1da538bd7 | NULL                                 |
| NULL                                 | e2d7fe3a-06e2-48df-a083-6c8eaeeefc22 |
| NULL                                 | fadc4d40-33b2-4545-98fe-e52d351c50f9 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

so room.code field is the available room. reservation.`status` = 1 means that booking have void so it will be the available room, because status booking when active is 0 so room.code is NULL

same happen in booking details

```
   mysql> SELECT
        -> stay_info.room, IF(booking_details.`status` = 1, room.code, (IF (stay_info.room IS null , room.code,null))) as code
        -> FROM stay_info
        -> INNER JOIN booking_details
        -> ON booking_details.stayInfo = stay_info.code
        -> RIGHT JOIN room
        -> ON stay_info.room = room.code
        -> INNER JOIN room_type
        -> ON room_type.code = room.roomType
        -> WHERE room_type.name = "Deluxe Double" ;





+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| room                                 | code                                 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 26a73433-d0cc-4e93-95d9-453d362e85a7 | NULL                                 |
| NULL                                 | 2b166d4f-2fe4-404c-beff-482c7d81c103 |
| NULL                                 | 3efc3bff-9c02-43ef-a494-e887a342c1f5 |
| NULL                                 | 7e0ebe37-a23a-46b6-9351-ba0c952ed33e |
| NULL                                 | 9574eb5f-58de-427f-859e-d8b61e289836 |
| NULL                                 | 9ee50e45-f92b-46bd-bf3e-fc818a96a81f |
| NULL                                 | d72f3f7e-c9d2-44d8-8767-66d2a1477a1b |
| NULL                                 | e25587a3-3dc1-4c0f-b4c2-68a1da538bd7 |
| NULL                                 | e2d7fe3a-06e2-48df-a083-6c8eaeeefc22 |
| NULL                                 | fadc4d40-33b2-4545-98fe-e52d351c50f9 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

when i combine two relation tables above with inner join

```
mysql> SELECT
-> stay_info.room,
-> IF((booking_details.`status` = 1 or reservation.`status` = 1), room.code, (IF (stay_info.room IS null , room.code,null))) as code
-> FROM stay_info
-> INNER JOIN booking_details
-> ON booking_details.stayInfo = stay_info.code
-> INNER JOIN reservation
-> ON reservation.stayInfo = stay_info.code
-> RIGHT JOIN room
-> ON stay_info.room = room.code
-> INNER JOIN room_type
-> ON room_type.code = room.roomType
-> WHERE room_type.name = "Deluxe Double" ;





+------+--------------------------------------+
| room | code                                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
| NULL | 26a73433-d0cc-4e93-95d9-453d362e85a7 |
| NULL | 2b166d4f-2fe4-404c-beff-482c7d81c103 |
| NULL | 3efc3bff-9c02-43ef-a494-e887a342c1f5 |
| NULL | 7e0ebe37-a23a-46b6-9351-ba0c952ed33e |
| NULL | 9574eb5f-58de-427f-859e-d8b61e289836 |
| NULL | 9ee50e45-f92b-46bd-bf3e-fc818a96a81f |
| NULL | d72f3f7e-c9d2-44d8-8767-66d2a1477a1b |
| NULL | e25587a3-3dc1-4c0f-b4c2-68a1da538bd7 |
| NULL | e2d7fe3a-06e2-48df-a083-6c8eaeeefc22 |
| NULL | fadc4d40-33b2-4545-98fe-e52d351c50f9 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
```

10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

what i expected for the combination is

```
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| room                                 | code                                 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| 26a73433-d0cc-4e93-95d9-453d362e85a7 | NULL                                 |
| NULL                                 | 2b166d4f-2fe4-404c-beff-482c7d81c103 |
| NULL                                 | 3efc3bff-9c02-43ef-a494-e887a342c1f5 |
| NULL                                 | 7e0ebe37-a23a-46b6-9351-ba0c952ed33e |
| NULL                                 | 9574eb5f-58de-427f-859e-d8b61e289836 |
| NULL                                 | 9ee50e45-f92b-46bd-bf3e-fc818a96a81f |
| NULL                                 | d72f3f7e-c9d2-44d8-8767-66d2a1477a1b |
| e25587a3-3dc1-4c0f-b4c2-68a1da538bd7 | NULL                                 |
| NULL                                 | e2d7fe3a-06e2-48df-a083-6c8eaeeefc22 |
| NULL                                 | fadc4d40-33b2-4545-98fe-e52d351c50f9 |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

so i will get easily the available room from code field

Comment: Its so hard to know what you need. Can you post schema of your tables and your cases then??

Comment: We need clear scenario instead the data of the tables. Can you explain  in words only?

Comment: like in the last table above i hope my combination is like that but unfortunately i don't know what query to make that i thought if INNER JOIN booking_details and reservation i will get my expectation result but the fact all of room field value is NULL, so code initial of room.code is the available room when i booked  or reservation the room.code is NULL and store the room.code at room initial of stay_info.room same behavior with booking_details.so from the code (room.code) i know the available room.

Comment: possible duplicate of [my sql queries 2 tables into 1 tables different case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731388/my-sql-queries-2-tables-into-1-tables-different-case)

Comment: You should have modified the existing question.  (Although I too find this opaque).  Your result data makes no sense, still.  What does `code` represent?  Why do you want to `null` it out if `room` is assigned?  Still wanting sample starting data (ie, the base rows in the tables).

Comment: actually code is primary key in the tables room, we can know the name of the room from the field called name in the room table. it is the encryption technique so if someone have got stolen the information from table he will know nothing. 
the reason why i assigned Null if room is out is i want to know what room is available in availability room, from that row of data i could handle the null and throw that null from datatable and then store it in generic List<T> so i can get the available room.

Answer (score 0):

i've found solution of my own question
this is the solution

> SELECT t_room_type.code, t_room_type.name,COUNT(t_room_type.name) AS
>   numRoom FROM t_room INNER JOIN t_room_type ON t_room.roomType =
>   t_room_type.code WHERE t_room.code NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT
>   t_stay_info.room FROM t_stay_info LEFT OUTER JOIN t_reservation ON
>   t_stay_info.code = t_reservation.stayInfo LEFT OUTER JOIN
>   t_booking_details ON t_stay_info.code = t_booking_details.stayInfo
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN t_walk_in ON t_stay_info.code = t_walk_in.stayInfo
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN t_stay_info_details ON t_stay_info.code =
>   t_stay_info_details.stayInfo WHERE t_stay_info_details.stayDate
>   BETWEEN '2014-07-16' AND '2014-07-17' AND (t_reservation.status = '0'
>   OR t_booking_details.status = '0' OR t_walk_in.status = '0')) GROUP BY
>   t_room_type.name ORDER BY t_room_type.name ASC